# Многомерный массив из обычного PHP

Tags: php, алгоритм, рекурсия

Как собрать многомерный массив из обычного

ИЗ:

```
$arr = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3'];
```

В:

```
$arr = [
     'Item 1' => [
        'Item 2' => [
            'Item 3 ' => ''
         ]
     ]
];
```

Comment: А ваши попытки? Что не получается?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

За исключением массива вместо строки на последнем уровне:

```
$arr = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3'];
$res = [];
$pt = &$res;
foreach ($arr as $el) {
    $pt[$el] = [];
    $pt = &$pt[$el];
}
unset($pt);

var_export($res);
```